# Does mysqldump return a status?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rails

I am creating a script that backups a mysql db using the mysqldump utility. I am writing this script in the shell "sh". I would like to capture the output status of mysqldump in the script (i.e. if the mysqldump command failed or succeeded) so I can report if the script was successful or not.

- Does mysqldump return an output status?
- Can someone please give me instructions on how to do this?

Comment: `$ mysqldump .......... && echo "Yes"` Replace the `...` part with the parameters. If the command is successful it will show `Yes` otherwise nothing will be shown

Comment: No exitcode/return value is mentioned in [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) or its [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/mysqldump.1.html). Note that `sh` is a symlink to `dash` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bash exit codes.

Pseudocode

```
if $? == 0 then successful else ....
```